# Converting a raw project into a Symfony project

Tags: php, symfony

I'm building a simple CMS system. In its raw version (which is without any frameworks - everything is written by me), it contains three base folders:

ADMIN
CONTENT
SYSTEM

---

ADMIN - displays the admin control panel, which is a set of classes responsible for all kinds of editions on the website etc.

CONTENT - handles generating a proper website, which contains all kinds of user "templates" etc.

SYSTEM - contains configuration system, etc.

---

Now, I'd like to implement Symfony here, so I would have to pack all these classes I mentioned above into src subfolders and bundles.

I haven't thought much about this yet, so my question is simple: **Is this a good idea to divide src folder into: admin, content, system subfolders,** and then divide their content into bundles?

Is it good to require everything in the project to use the MVC pattern like I'm doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's better to map your three functionals into sepereate bundles

```
YourAdminBundle
YourContentBundle
YourSystemBundle
```

Their content can divided into different controllers into the bundles. If you have some big functionality you can split this into a seperate bundle.